# Convert map array json to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

Hello all I'm very new to python, so just bear with me.
I have a sample json file in this format.

```
[{
"5":"5",
"0":"0",
"1":"1"},{
"14":"14",
"11":"11",
"15":"15"},{
"25":"25",
"23":"23",
"22":"22"}]
```

I would like to convert the json file to csv in a specific way. All the values in 1 map i.e., `{` and `}` in the json should be converted to a csv file(say FILE_A.csv).

For the above example,

FILE_A.csv,

```
DAILY,COUNT
5,5
0,0
1,1
```

FILE_B.csv,

```
WEEKLY,COUNT
14,14
11,11
15,15
```

FILE_C.csv,

```
MONTHLY,COUNT
25,25
23,23
22,22
```

There will only be 3 maps in the json.

**Can anyone suggest the best way to convert the 3 maps in the json to 3 different csv files of the above structure?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you going to store column names in json?

Comment: @Dmitry: In json column names are not present. I'd like to add the column names in each of the 3 files.

Comment: @Rowen This is rather standard reading in via the `json` module, looping over the list and outputting via the `csv` module. I suggest you look at some python introduction (such as [this](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/a-whirlwind-tour-of-python.csp) or [this](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/language/python_language.html)), make a first attempt and then come back with some of the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data_list = [{
"5":"5",
"0":"0",
"1":"1"},{
"14":"14",
"11":"11",
"15":"15"},{
"25":"25",
"23":"23",
"22":"22"}]

temp_dct = { "DAILY": data_list[0], "WEEKLY": data_list[1], "MONTHLY": data_list[2]}
file_name_ord = 65
for k in ["DAILY", "WEEKLY", "MONTHLY"]:
    v = temp_dct[k]
    file_name = "FILE_"+str(chr(file_name_ord))+".csv"
    file_name_ord+=1
    data = k + ","+ "COUNT\n" 
    for inner_k, inner_v in v.items():
        data += inner_k + ","+inner_v+"\n"

    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Try this one also. Hope you will get your answer.

Comment: Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop with all the data you need, should look like this:

```
jsondata = [{
"5":"5",
"0":"0",
"1":"1"},{
"14":"14",
"11":"11",
"15":"15"},{
"25":"25",
"23":"23",
"22":"22"}]

for name, timelapse, data in zip(("A", "B", "C"), 
                                 ("DAILY", "WEEKLY","MONTHLY",), 
                                 jsondata): #get data together
    with open("path/to/your/FILE_{}".format(name), "w") as f:
        f.write("{}, COUNT\n".format(timelapse)) # write header
        f.write("\n".join(",".join((k,v)) for k,v in data.items())) #write data separated by ','
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/LWBO/1)

Also take a look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

Comment: Can u please tell me why i'm getting this error `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` in this line `f.write("\n".join(",".join((k,v) for k,v in data)))`?

Comment: I did not use `items` method on the dict, i updated the answer

Comment: Now for the same statement, its throwing following error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found`. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Straight-forward solution:

```
import json, csv    

with open('FILE_A.csv', 'w', newline='') as fa, open('FILE_B.csv', 'w', newline='') as fb, \
     open('FILE_C.csv', 'w', newline='') as fc:

    a_writer, b_writer, c_writer = csv.writer(fa), csv.writer(fb), csv.writer(fc)
    da, db, dc = json.load(open('your.json'))

    a_writer.writerow(('DAILY','COUNT'))
    a_writer.writerows(da.items())

    b_writer.writerow(('WEEKLY','COUNT'))
    b_writer.writerows(db.items())

    c_writer.writerow(('MONTHLY','COUNT'))
    c_writer.writerows(dc.items())
```